# How to round the date to the first day of the month when subtracting dates in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I need to calculate the difference between the current month and the last.
I do so

```
library(lubridate)
last_month <- Sys.Date() - months(1)
```

and the result

```
> last_month
[1] "2022-12-04"
```

This is the correct answer, but I need the received date to always be from the first day
like this  `"2022-12-01"`.

That is, round it up to the first day of the month?

For example, when I do this in February,4 day , the result will be
`"2023-01-04"`, but i need that it would be `"2023-01-01"`.

How to round the date to the first day of the month when subtracting dates like this?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `format`, i.e.

```
format(Sys.Date() - months(1), '%Y-%m-01')
#[1] "2022-12-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `floor_date` from `lubridate` based on month like this:

```r
library(lubridate)
last_month <- Sys.Date() - months(1)
floor_date(last_month, "month")
#> [1] "2022-12-01"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>